# unable to access openzeppelin.com

Tags: openzeppelin

I clone the repo from GitHub and then try to install its dependencies by running `forge build` command, but it's not installed, So I run `forge build` multiple time but still not installed.
When I see https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/  I'm blocked.

Actually, I send message to the security@openzeppelin.com, but they didn't answer me yet.

[image]

Comment: The OZ Wizard site and the package of contracts are likely unconnected - one is a website, the other is a repository in Github.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are stuck to install zeppelin into your project. is it?
if it yes! than you can run :
`forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts --no-commit`
and set the path into your gitmodules to access it easily into particular file:

```
path = lib/openzeppelin-contracts
URL = https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
```

I hope this solves your problem but i don't know how to unblocked your wizard  zeppelin website.